# scipy 1.7.x from source build error with python 3.7.x on macbook M1 Sonoma

Tags: python, installation, scipy, clang, apple-m1

I need to install SciPy version 1.7.0 -1.7.3 with python 3.7.0 - 3.7.17 on macbook M1 Sonoma 14.0. To work with python version 3.7.17 on M1, I use pyenv.

I have gcc, gfortran, openblas, pkg-config installed via brew. The versions are listed below.

Cython, pybind11, pythran, numpy are also installed. The versions are listed below.

Initially there was a Cython error, but I found out by experience that the version should be Cython<3. And now I'm getting a lower-level compilation error. Maybe I need to use a different version of the Mac OS X.sdk? Or change the versions of dependent packages in a special way?

```
$OPENBLAS=$(brew --prefix openblas) CFLAGS="-falign-functions=8 ${CFLAGS}" pip3 install --no-binary :all: --no-use-pep517 scipy==1.7.3
```

```
[...]
In file included from scipy/spatial/ckdtree.cxx:1007:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/complex:1401:53: error: expected unqualified-id
          if (__x.real() == 0 && (__x.imag() == 0 || std::isnan(__x.imag())))
                                                          ^
      scipy/_lib/_c99compat.h:124:30: note: expanded from macro 'isnan'
                  #define isnan(x) ((x) != (x))
                                   ^
      1 warning and 1 error generated.
      error: Command "clang++ -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -falign-functions=8 -I/opt/homebrew/opt/imagemagick@6/include -I/Users/dwdsf/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/include/python3.7m -I/Users/dwdsf/workflow/alfa/fs_backend_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -Iscipy/_lib -Iscipy/_build_utils/src -Iscipy/spatial/ckdtree/src -I/Users/dwdsf/workflow/alfa/fs_backend_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-11.6-arm64-3.7/numpy/distutils/include -I/Users/dwdsf/workflow/alfa/fs_backend_api/venv/include -I/Users/dwdsf/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/include/python3.7m -c scipy/spatial/ckdtree.cxx -o build/temp.macosx-11.6-arm64-cpython-37/scipy/spatial/ckdtree.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-11.6-arm64-cpython-37/scipy/spatial/ckdtree.o.d -std=c++14 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9" failed with exit status 1
      
      ########### EXT COMPILER OPTIMIZATION ###########
      Platform      :
        Architecture: aarch64
        Compiler    : clang
      
      CPU baseline  :
        Requested   : 'min'
        Enabled     : NEON NEON_FP16 NEON_VFPV4 ASIMD
        Flags       : none
        Extra checks: none
      
      CPU dispatch  :
        Requested   : 'max -xop -fma4'
        Enabled     : ASIMDHP ASIMDDP
        Generated   : none
      CCompilerOpt.cache_flush[809] : write cache to path -> /private/var/folders/tk/m40lxrrx49vf4s05nf9wt5_c0000gn/T/pip-install-r_a3ufrb/scipy_ffa7d0ec687a4ad8bb86f38250ba2117/build/temp.macosx-11.6-arm64-cpython-37/ccompiler_opt_cache_ext.py
      
      ########### CLIB COMPILER OPTIMIZATION ###########
      Platform      :
        Architecture: aarch64
        Compiler    : clang
      
      CPU baseline  :
        Requested   : 'min'
        Enabled     : NEON NEON_FP16 NEON_VFPV4 ASIMD
        Flags       : none
        Extra checks: none
      
      CPU dispatch  :
        Requested   : 'max -xop -fma4'
        Enabled     : ASIMDHP ASIMDDP
        Generated   : none
      CCompilerOpt.cache_flush[809] : write cache to path -> /private/var/folders/tk/m40lxrrx49vf4s05nf9wt5_c0000gn/T/pip-install-r_a3ufrb/scipy_ffa7d0ec687a4ad8bb86f38250ba2117/build/temp.macosx-11.6-arm64-cpython-37/ccompiler_opt_cache_clib.py
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure
```

My versions:

```
gcc/13.2.0
openblas/0.3.24
pkg-config/0.29.2_3

Cython/0.29.36
pybind11/2.11.1
pythran/0.14.0
numpy/1.21.6

xcode-select version 2399.
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm experience exact the same thing as you were. Need to get `scipy` with `python3.7` down into `arm64` platform. Same `Cython` problem if version is over 3. Same `clang` compile error and everything.

I believe the problem lies in the define statement:

```
#define isnan(x) ((x) != (x))
```

This line is meant to shortcut the function `isnan(x)` to use `((x) != (x))` instead while compiling.

I'm guessing that in a later version of clang, it just doesn't allow the syntax like (xxxx) anymore for some reason. So I guess we should either downgrade clang to a certain version, or add some parameters to bypass that compile check or something. Unluckily I'm not any sort of good at c/c++, but will try what I could later.

Will update here if I figure out anything related.

By the way would you please share any of your progress now?

---

Update:

Just now compiled smoothly with **clang 13**(llvm@13 via brew). Exact same install command as yours. Just make sure you use a lower version of clang for compiling.

I haven't tried with clang 12 but I'm pretty sure it should be good as well. After all, apple's macOS SDK gotta be clang 12 for macOSX 12 .

[image]
(Have to mask my company's pypi source)

---

For anyone who's not so sure about how to install or temporarily use a separate clang for compiling, here's how.

```bash
brew install llvm@13
```

After installation, you should notice from brew that there're some configuration you need to setup. Basically you need to set up `PATH` to make sure the installed executable binary files are first selected.

```bash
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"
```

I also set `LDFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS` as instructed

```bash
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/c++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/c++"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/include"
```

(not very sure if CPPFLAGS is needed, but did it anyway)

Then install pip

```bash
OPENBLAS=$(brew --prefix openblas) pip3 install --no-use-pep517 scipy==1.7.3
```

(LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS}" is not needed if it is already your env variable.)